# Revert error when transfering available amount of ETH

Tags: transfer

I'm trying to code a reward pool distribution system and I'm unable to do the following (in that order).

- A deposits X amount (user_deposit)
- B deposits Y amount (user_deposit)
- C deposits Z amount of rewards (depositRewards)

(order doesn't matter on the 2 following steps)

- A withdraws
- B withdraws

The second withdrawal always fails with this error:
The transaction has been reverted to the initial state.
Note: The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be
less than your current balance.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract ETHPool {

mapping(address => bool) internal team_members;
uint256 public poolValue;
uint256 internal rewards;
address internal contractAdmin;
uint256 public rewards_timestamp;
uint256 public claimable_rewards;

struct User_Transactions {
    uint256 amount;
    uint256 deposit_timestamp;
}

mapping(address => User_Transactions[]) internal deposits;

constructor() {
    contractAdmin = msg.sender;
}

function update_team(address _memberAddress, bool _isAllowed) public {
    require(msg.sender == contractAdmin, "Function only callable by contract admin.");
    team_members[_memberAddress] = _isAllowed;
}

function depositRewards() public payable {
    require(team_members[msg.sender] == true, "Only team members are allowed to deposit rewards");
    rewards += msg.value;
    claimable_rewards += msg.value;
    rewards_timestamp = block.timestamp; 
}

function user_deposit() public payable {
    deposits[msg.sender].push(User_Transactions(msg.value, block.timestamp));
    poolValue += msg.value;
}

function withdraw() public {

    require(deposits[msg.sender].length > 0, "You have no deposits on your behalf.");
    uint256 valueAddedUntilNow;
    uint256 totalValueAdded;

    for (uint i=0; i < deposits[msg.sender].length; i++) {
        if (deposits[msg.sender][i].deposit_timestamp < rewards_timestamp) {
            valueAddedUntilNow += deposits[msg.sender][i].amount;                
        }
        totalValueAdded += deposits[msg.sender][i].amount;
    }

    uint256 share_of_pool = (valueAddedUntilNow * 100) / poolValue;
    payable(msg.sender).transfer((rewards / 100) * share_of_pool + valueAddedUntilNow); 
    claimable_rewards -= (rewards / 100) * share_of_pool;
    poolValue -= valueAddedUntilNow;
    delete deposits[msg.sender];
}
}
```

Comment: Comment unrelated to your question: I would discourage the use of `transfer`. See https://consensys.net/diligence/blog/2019/09/stop-using-soliditys-transfer-now/

Comment: Another thing that you should be aware of are rounding errors. If you perform `x / 100` on a integer you are losing the decimals

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you perform `A withdraws` you reduce `poolValue`.  When you then perform `B withdraws` and calculate the `share_of_pool` based on this new `poolValue` it will result in a poll share of `100`. This will result in the reward that should be added to the amount that should be transferred to be equal to `rewards`, but at this point we don't have all of the `rewards` available anymore, as part as already been claimed by A.

Comment: Thank you! It was the classic error "being blind af". Appreciate it!